# Server Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

I am helping a friend out with his new startup and he is looking into the possiblity of buying a server. A big part of the business involves running scripts to test various programs. The scripts automate mouse movement and clicks and keyboard inputs, basically mimicing a human user and logging how to program responds.

I understand that using virtualization, he could have one server running multiple instances of the operating system simulatnously. Unfortunately I don't have any experience with this.

What we would need to do is as follows:

- Open an instance of remote desktop instance on the server through a       laptop.
- Run one of the automation scripts and watch the mouse move around the screen doing its work
- Close the remote desktop on my laptop but leave the script running with the mouse moving around the virtual screen doing its work
- Open 10 more instances of remote desktop to do the same thing
- Login to each remote desktop a week later and check the progress

Basically if I close an instance of remote desktop, is there a way to keep the automated mouse movement script running?

Is there a limit to the number of instances that can be run at once?

I'd be greatful if someone could point me to some instructions on how this would work? As you could probably guess neither of us are IT experts! Thank you